# Failed to parse time string: it is working good on my local but on server

Tags: php, datetime, fatal-error

I have a code which is working on my localhost but in server it throws error.
the error is: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@1645.0000000006) at position 14 (0): Unexpected character`

my code is:

```
function secondsToTime($seconds)
{
    $arr = array();
    $dtF = new DateTime('@0');
    $dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    $arr[0] = $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h');
    $arr[1] = $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%i');
    $arr[2] = $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%s');
    return $arr;
}
print_r(secondsToTime("1645.0000000006"));
```

what is the problem? thanks everyone

Comment: Differences in PHP versions…? https://3v4l.org/kNd7r

Comment: Why You use '@' character ?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan now I remove '@' , but it still is not working! the problem and confusing thing is that it is working on my local!

Comment: @Vahe To tell PHP to interpret the number as UNIX timestamp.

Comment: `"1645.0000000006"` < not a valid date/time string

Comment: @CD001 `"1645.0000000006"` < Valid UNIX timestamp (at least as of PHP 7).

Comment: @deceze ~ 00:27 on the 1st of Jan 1970?

Comment: @CD001 Yup, OP is diffing that with `@0`, abusing time functions for duration calculations…

Comment: @deceze tested it but that is not the problem!

Comment: Tested what exactly? What PHP version(s) are you using?

Comment: @deceze how can i change it to work in php 5.6.34

Comment: @deceze - oki not a valid date/time string for the version of PHP running on the server then :P So you were spot on with the first comment (which I missed)

Comment: @deceze I change php version from 5.6.34 to 7.1 but exactly that error was returning!

Comment: You want to convert second to minute?

Comment: @PPL OfCourse not! I am trying to get different time
hour,minutes,seconds

Comment: Why are you running `$dtF->diff($dtT)` three times? Overkill...

Comment: Small **benchmark: https://eval.in/983052**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently handling of microseconds changed around PHP 7.1 and PHP accepts decimal values as valid timestamps starting with that version, but not before. If you have to make it compatible with previous versions, you need to cast your float to an int:

```
$dtT = new DateTime('@' . (int)$seconds);
```